# .NET Core Page after building on IIS throws 400 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express

I was working on a page in .NET Core, when suddenly I couldn't connect, Chrome started throwing 400 error and Firefox shows nothing and in console they say something about encoding, even though I have it defined like so: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. After checking it out, even sample pages won't work (or my previous projects) - all yield the same result. Strange thing it works in Incognito, but will eventually disconnect and stop working there as well.

[image: after clicking IIS Express in Visual Studio]

[image: IIS]

Fixed by clearing cookies for localhost

Comment: Look at the Output window. What errors do you see?

Comment: Thanks.. I missed that completly it's: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Malformed request: invalid headers.
`

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you have many plugins in Chrome, try disabling them

Comment: Thank you, I was very hesitant to post this question, but now I know what's wrong - I saved my cookies without any encoding (?) at least that's what i think happened, thanks yet again! Never thought to see in Output window

Comment: That's kind of weird, but being a Cookies problem does make sense to me (that's why it works in Incognito). You may want to add an answer with whatever you had to fix when you added cookies